# Oracle transportable tablespace not bring packages and procedures

Tags: oracle

Is there some way to bring packages and procedures of a schema during the transportable tablespace export/import? in me research it seems all plsql for all users is actually stored by by the SYS user in SYSTEM tablespace. If i am exporting foo tablespace (`transport_tablespaces=foo`) used by schema foo, those objects (`packages, procedures and functions`) don't come with the tablespace foo because it is in system tablespace.

The only way I've found to import those object (`packages, procedures and functions`) is, after finish the transportable tablespace import, make a new export of the schema in the source database with the option `content=metadata_only` and then, reimport it in target database. Is the the only way? (two steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No option for that with the transportable tablespace feature.

Full Transportable Export/Import can do it.

[Introduction to Full Transportable Export/Import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/transporting-data.html#GUID-AA3C177A-EBD8-459B-9F25-19F13C304EEE)

> You can use the full transportable export/import feature to copy an
> entire database from one Oracle Database instance to another.

[Limitations on Full Transportable Export/import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/transporting-data.html#GUID-5A1ECB8A-63BC-471B-9BD0-6474ABFF9AA2)

> Full transportable export/import can export and import user-defined
> database objects in administrative tablespaces using conventional Data
> Pump export/import, such as direct path or external table.
> Administrative tablespaces are non-user tablespaces supplied with
> Oracle Database, such as the SYSTEM and SYSAUX tablespaces.

[Full Transportable Export and Import](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/full-transportable-wp-18c-4394831.pdf)

> Full transportable export/import greatly simplifies and accelerates
> the process of database migration. Combining the ease of use of Oracle
> Data Pump with the performance of transportable tablespaces, full
> transportable export/import gives you the ability to upgrade or
> migrate to Oracle Database in a single operation if your source
> database is at least Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3).